# how can i get the python 'json' list, dictionary Importing mixed data

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

i want print, python 'json' list, dictionary Importing mixed data

exam json data

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "rows": [
                {
                    "dimensions": [
                        {
                            "value": "title1"
                        }
                    ],
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "value": "potato"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "sweetpotato"
                        },
                        {
                            "conversion_annotation_value": []
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "123123"
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

As far as I know, i use try

```
itemlist = json.loads(r.text)
for i in itemlist['data']['rows']['dimensions']:
...
for i in itemlist['data']['rows']['metrics']:
...
```

error, i was see

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

i want see, this json data

```
'title1'
'123123'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are lists inside each dict. So you need to access them like list elements first:

```
for i in itemlist['data'][0]['rows'][0]['dimensions']:
    print(i.get('value'))
for i in itemlist['data'][0]['rows'][0]['metrics']:
    print(i.get('value'))
```

Comment: thanks~!  I'll edit a little more for a perfect result~!

Answer (score 1):

Use `itemlist['data']['rows'].get('dimensions', [])` instead using the `.get()` property of a dict.

Or a bit more generally:

```
itemlist = json.loads(r.text)
for k, v in itemlist['data']['rows']:
  for i in v:
    if k == 'a':
      # code ....
    elif k == 'b':
      # code ....
    # ...
```